# JSON output of a table in PHP

Tags: php, json

This question is not an programming question exactly. I have a requirement of making a JSON output of the picture shown. I know the usage of `json_encode()` but the problem is I am not getting how logically I will show these details.

The output I got is:

```
{"name":"ZXY","success":1,"subjects":["DIGITAL COMMUNICATION TECHNIQUE(2012-13)","DIGITAL SIGNAL PROCESSING(2012-13)","ANTENNAS AND WAVE PROPAGATION(2012-13)","DIGITAL SWITCHING THEORY AND NETWORKS(2012-13)","ACCOUNTING FOR MANAGERS(2012-13)","DIGITAL COMMUNICATION TECHNIQUE LAB(2012-13)","DIGITAL SIGNAL PROCESSING LAB(2012-13)"]}
```

[image: Pic showing the details].

Please tell me what can be a valid JSON output of the details I have,

**Edit:** I have to get a JSON output from the MySQL data. A sample data of a student I have provided in the image. The JSON Which I have shown is the result of a PHP page, I am not satisfied with the JSON output I am getting. I am asking for a better way to represent the data in effective manner in JSON format.

This is the PHP code which I have written for getting JSON output.

```
<?php

$regno = $_GET['regno'];

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'android_app_details';
$dbc = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database)
    or die('Error in connecting the database');


$query = 

    "SELECT SD.REGNO, STD.FNAME, STD.MNAME, STD.LNAME, SD.SUBJECT_NAME, AD.PRESENT_COUNT, AD.TOTAL_COUNT ".
    "FROM ATTENDANCE_DETAILS AS AD, SUBJECT_DETAILS AS SD, STUDENT_DETAILS STD ".
    "WHERE AD.ENROLLMENT_ID = SD.ENROLLMENT_ID ".
    "AND SD.REGNO = '".$regno."' ".
    "AND AD.BATCH_SUBJECT_ID = SD.BATCH_SUBJECT_ID ".
    "AND SD.STUDENT_ID = STD.STUDENT_ID ";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error in query');

$subject = Array();
$att = Array();
$total = Array();
$i = 0;
$success = 0;


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if($row['MNAME'])
        $name = $row['FNAME'].' '.$row['MNAME'].' '.$row['LNAME'];
    else
        $name = $row['FNAME'].' '.$row['LNAME'];
    $subject[$i] = $row['SUBJECT_NAME'];
    $i++;
    $success = 1;
}

if($success)
    $response = array(
        "name" => $name,
        "success" => $success,
        "subjects" => $subject
    );
else
    $response = array(
        "success" => $success
    );
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: what exactly is wrong with your current JSON output?

Comment: Well, first of all the subjects are not having any `tagnames` hence accessing them would be difficult..

Comment: subjects do have a tag name which is `subjects`. They're simply in an array and you can access each of them iterating the array using `subjects[i]`. What different tagname would you want for them?

Comment: As per my knowledge, JSON array is a collection of json objects. JSON objects are enclosed with `{}` right? As per this definition the array is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

You output is pefectly well formed JSON (as expected from `json_encode` function).

From your comments I see what upsests you is that `subjects:[...]` array which you second as not valid, but it is.

What **JSON**, as well as **xml** and other *structured data formats* are all about is **structured data** which holds in its definition both **structure** and **data** so if you have:

```
{object:
    {subobject:{subobjectName:"Penny"}
}
```

You'll have a **structure** which is all the `object->subobject->subobjectName` three and some **data** which is `"Penny"`.

Now we can see a **JSON array** as a *collection of entities with the same tagname*, for example like this:

```
{object:{
    subobjects:[
        {subobjectName:"Penny",subobjectLasName:"Rose"},
        {subobjectName:"Lewis",subobjectLasName:"Armstrong"},
        ...
    ]
}}
```

Which would have the `{}s` you were looking for, but if you look at it in means of *structure/data* this last array is an **array of structures**(objects), so its elements are JSON objects.

What you have in your posted JSON output is an **array of data**(Strings) which *are not structural elements and do not have any specific tagname* other than `subjecs`.

If you are familiar with XML this should be easier to understand:

```
<student>

    <name>Penny</name>
    <last_name>Rose</last_name>
    <subjects>Subject1</subjects>
    <subjects>Subject2</subjects>
    <subjects>Subject3</subjects>

</student>
```

this above is a valid XML and translates in some JSON of the kind you have in your output, this is because those `Subject1, Subject2, Subject3` text entities do not have any parent tagname but `subjects` which is an array of tags with the same name containing plain text.

I know this doesn't answer your question, but I hope it clears your dubts about the output you got.